# Extracting records not found on another table

Tags: mysql

I have this table...

```
id          name          location          date_created
--          ----          --------          ------------

15641       Maybel        New York          2015-09-15
84194       Joseph        Arkansas          2015-02-03
36479       Frank         Illinois          2015-10-28
19804       Samantha      San Francisco     2015-11-05
67811       Charles       Texas             2015-11-05
```

... and this table...

```
id          name          location          created_at
--          ----          --------          ----------
15641       Maybel        New York          2015-09-15
84194       Joseph        Arkansas          2015-02-03
36479       Frank         Illinois          2015-10-28
78916       Logan         Philadelphia      2015-12-01
26799       George        Mississippi       2015-12-10
```

and what I need is...

```
id          name          location          created_at
--          ----          --------          ----------
19804       Samantha      San Francisco     2015-11-05
67811       Charles       Texas             2015-11-05
```

So basically I need a query to show only the records on table 1 that are not found in table 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
Left join table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```